# fetch big number of data in blade and pdf print in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, database, eloquent

i need to fetch around 30k records from the database to be shown **ALL** in the blade and in PDF print

i have tried the following method but each one has a problem

1- I have used paginate() it works fine in the blade but when I need to print it ALL in paper using PDF I only get the first page 200 records

```
        $accounts = Acc_account::where('cat', 2)->paginate(200)
```

2- I have used chunk() but I could not use it in the blade

```
        $accounts = Acc_account::where('cat', 2)->chunk(200, function (account) {
            foreach ($accounts as $account) {
                //
            }
        }); ;
```

3- I have used get() and all() but because the data is big I get 500 error

Comment: In order for you to generate your report, you will likely need to narrow the scope of your query. Instead of fetching all columns and all rows, you need to simply request the specific data that you'll want to output onto your pdf report. This becomes especially true if you're related tables (one-to-one, many-to-one, etc) also have a lot of data and/or they're not being lazy loaded. Eager loading could be causing your issues. But without seeing your db model, it would be difficult to tell the bottleneck. A table of 3k entries should be no problem, depending on the schema.

Comment: how do you expect to read your pdf if it's gonna have 30k records in it? Maybe an excel or csv would be better.

Comment: The issue is that you are loading all pdf in memory. Same problem will be with excel in php. You can use csv and chunks and store the csv on disk not in the project. Excel js can stream data from browser memory to disk. Php excel lib can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

For better performance you can use `cursor` instead of `chunk` or `all`.
The query will be like that: `$accounts = Acc_account::where('cat', 2)->cursor();`
Or you can use `LazyCollection` to handle the memory issue.
**Note that all of those methods does not guarantee** complete solution of the your problem as I don't think large data would be a good solution for a PDF Maybe an excel or csv would be better.